# How to keep the SplitBar when panel collapsed in SplitContainer?

Tags: c#, winforms

I found that when a panel collapse in splitcontainer, the splitbar is hided either.

```
splitContainer1.Panel2Collapsed = true;
```

I would like to use double click the split bar to toggle panel2.

How to keep the split bar when one panel is collapse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't collapse it:

```
sc.Panel2MinSize = 0;
sc.SplitterDistance = sc.ClientSize.Width - sc.SplitterWidth;
```